# What is the getCSSCanvasContext() method of an HTML5 element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What is the `getCSSCanvasContext()` method? I saw it in Chrome’s debuging console, but I cannot find any decent documentation for it.

Does it mean we can draw using canvas commands on any element?

Comment: It's worth noting that this method is deprecated in recent chrome builds and is probably going to be removed: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/WvqvdsmiQzg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method is implemented in WebKit (meaning you can also use it in Safari) and returns an object that lets you draw into a CSS image. See this [blog post](http://webkit.org/blog/176/css-canvas-drawing/) for an example:

> In the latest nightlies, you can try out a new feature: the ability to
>   specify named image buffers in CSS and then to draw into them
>   programmatically from JavaScript. Here’s how it works.
>
> `background: -webkit-canvas(mycanvas);`
>
> Instead of specifying an image URL, you specify a canvas and an
>   identifier to use for that canvas. The following new API on documents
>   can then be used to obtain a drawing context for that canvas.
>
> `CanvasRenderingContext getCSSCanvasContext(in DOMString contextType, in DOMString identifier, in long width, in long height);`

Comment: Please note that this method has been deprecated and removed from all Chromium platforms in M48: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/WvqvdsmiQzg

Answer (score 0):

also don't use      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);  for IE9 - it doesn't work after this code if you try to draw something after clearRect() you will get empty canvas anyway